# Does the choice of orientations of $V$ and $W$ determine an orientation of $V\oplus W$?

Tags: solution-verification, vector-spaces, determinant, orientation

Let $V$ and $W$ be two finite-dimensional real vector spaces. I guess that there is only one way to interpret the title (if my guess is wrong, then please let me know), but here is what I mean:

Suppose we have chosen an orientation for $V$ and an orientation for $W$. We can choose a positive basis $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ of $V$ and a positive basis $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ of $W$. If the orientation of the basis $$e_1,\ldots,e_{m+n}:=(v_1,0),\ldots,(v_m,0),(0,w_1),\ldots,(0,w_n)$$turns out to be independent of the chosen bases, then this determines an orientation of $V\oplus W$ in dependence of the chosen orientations of $V$ and $W$.

I think that the answer is YES. Here is my attempt of a proof: We want to show that
$$e_1,\ldots,e_{m+n}:=(v_1,0),\ldots,(v_m,0),(0,w_1),\ldots,(0,w_n)$$
and
$$\tilde e_1,\ldots,\tilde e_{m+n}:=(\tilde v_1,0),\ldots,(\tilde v_m,0),(0,\tilde w_1),\ldots,(0,\tilde w_n)$$
have the same orientations if

- $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ and $\tilde v_1,\ldots,\tilde v_m$ have the same orientation and
- $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ and $\tilde w_1,\ldots,\tilde w_n$ have the same orientation.

Set $M_{ij}=e^i\tilde e_j$, $A_{ij}=v^i\tilde v_j$ and $B_{ij}=w^i\tilde w_j$, then I assume that
\begin{equation}
M=\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\
0&B\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and hence $\det M=\det A\det B>0$, which shows that $e$ and $\tilde e$ have the same orientation.

Comment: What you did is fine.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you for the confirmation!